# Insert an URL the ends with Value as parameter programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of names that attached to IDs and I like to generate URL that has a format and ends with ID number, I want to add the ID at the end of the URL programmatically, like:

`https://profile2u.com/id={Variable}`

[image]

Comment: You can do this with a simple formula, eg `=IF(A2="","",HYPERLINK("https://profile2u.com/id="&A2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already written as comment: No need to use VBA for that, just put a simple formula using `Hyperlink` into the cells. You can even copy it down to rows that are not already filled.

Formula is `=IF(A2="","",HYPERLINK("https://profile2u.com/id="&A2))`